# Изменение внешнего вида (темы) visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

В общем при гуглении различных тем для изменения внешнего вида IDE (пример ниже на фото, но это вроде Atom или Visual Code) в интернете можно найти только различные темы для Visual Studio Code.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю, что можно вручную устанавливать различные цвета для текста, но можно ли в VS менять разные темы (кроме светлой и темной) так же автоматически, как в VSCode или Atom и если да, то где их найти и как установить?

P.S. Если не совсем понятно что за темы для VSCode то вот пример сайта с ними - vscodethemes.com

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите на кнопку "Средства", потом "Параметры", потом выберите тему, которая Вам нравится.

Comment: ..`можно ли в VS менять разные темы (кроме светлой и темной!!!)`...

Comment: Да. Там кроме темной и светлой темы есть синяя и синий (дополнительный контраст)

Comment: отредактировал вопрос чтобы было понятно